# COUNT returned rows from JOIN depending on columns

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I'm going to try to make it clear.

First of all here are the tables :

CARROSSERIE

```
MARQ      MODEL     SILHOUETTE   ID

citroen   c3        coupe        1
citroen   c3        sport        2
citroen   c4        coupe        3
citroen   c4        sport        4
acura     cdx       cuv          5
...       ...       ...          ...
```

table2 has the same fields as table1 but with some more fields (only 1 is interesting me)

alltable

```
 SAME AS TABLE1      zone      
 ...                 EUR
 ...                 EUR
 ...                 USA
 ...                 RUS
 ...                 CHI
 ...                 ...
```

So I just simply join table1 and table2 on their similar fields to get "zone" from table2.

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT C.model_marq AS model_marq, C.model_name AS model_name, C.silhouette AS silhouette, IIF(T.ZONE IS NULL, 'ROW', T.ZONE) AS zone
    INTO zone_vehicule
    FROM CARROSSERIE C
    LEFT JOIN alltable T
    ON C.model_marq= T.MARQUE
    AND C.model_name = T.MODELE
    AND C.silhouette = T.CARROS
    GROUP BY model_marq, model_name, silhouette, zone
```

I'm getting the good result as I get all the "zone" from table2 depending on the fields of table1.
The problem is that there is something I need to handle in this query:

if the cars from table1 (fields model_marq, model_name, silhouette) are in 7 different zones from table2 (7 zones are in fact all the possible zones), I get in the resultset :

```
MARQ      MODEL     SILHOUETTE   zone

citroen   c3        coupe        EUR
citroen   c3        coupe        CHIN
citroen   c3        coupe        ASI
citroen   c3        coupe        RUS
citroen   c3        coupe        AML
...       ...       ...          etc(all the 7 zones)
```

which is totaly normal with the query i'm using.
What I would like is that if the query returns this case (a car is in all the 7 zones), instead of having 7 rows in the resultset with all the different zones I want only 1 row with '*' in zone field (in fact it would merge the 7 rows in 1 rows only when it is in all the zones)

An example of the result I would need:

```
MARQ      MODEL     SILHOUETTE   zone

citroen   c3        coupe        * (because it was in all the 7 zones)
citroen   c3        sport        CHIN
citroen   c3        sport        RUS
citroen   c3        sport        EUR 
citroen   c4        cuv          AML
acura     cdx       sport        *
acura     cdx       coupe        EUR
...       ...       ...          ...
```

I don't know where to start from there.
I hope it was clear enough to be understood. Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me but I think it's a bit complicated and long for my need. I'll try to use @TPhe answer to improve it.

```
SELECT model_marq, model_name, silhouette, zone into ZONE_MODELE FROM
(SELECT C.marque AS model_marq, C.modele AS model_name, C.carros AS silhouette, IIF(T.ZONE IS NULL, IIF(model_name = 'DIVERS', '*', 'ROW'), IIF(C.countzones = 7, '*', T.ZONE)) AS zone, C.countzones as countzones FROM (SELECT marque, modele, carros, count(*) as countzones FROM (SELECT marque, modele, carros, zone from (SELECT CA.model_marq AS marque, CA.model_name AS modele, CA.silhouette AS carros, IIF(TMP.ZONE IS NULL, 'ROW', TMP.ZONE) AS zone FROM CARROSSERIE CA LEFT JOIN alltable TMP ON CA.model_marq = TMP.MARQUE AND CA.model_name = TMP.MODELE AND CA.silhouette = TMP.CARROS GROUP BY CA.model_marq, CA.model_name, CA.silhouette, TMP.ZONE ) group by  marque, modele, carros, zone) a GROUP BY marque, modele, carros) C LEFT JOIN alltable T ON C.marque= T.MARQUE AND C.modele = T.MODELE AND C.carros = T.CARROS GROUP BY C.marque, C.modele, C.carros, zone, countzones) TMP2 GROUP BY model_marq, model_name, silhouette, zone
```

If anyone knows how to make the same simplified query I would appreciate

Comment: Can you format that code a bit to make it more readable? It's hard to understand when it's all on one line like that.

Answer (score 1):

My approach uses a subquery to find just the cars that have 7 zones listed, and then uses that subquery's results to inform the main query's IIF statement determining the "zone" field. It makes some assumptions that may not prove to be correct, depending on your data, such as that the `alltable` has something like a `carId` that is an id for each car you need to look at, and that if you count the number of rows for each `carId` it will return the number of distinct zones. You can tweak the query as needed, depending on the actual situation, but hopefully the concept is clear:

```
SELECT C.model_marq AS model_marq, C.model_name AS model_name, C.silhouette AS silhouette, IIF(T.ZONE IS NULL, 'ROW', iff(allZones.carId is not null, "*",  T.ZONE) AS zone
    INTO zone_vehicule
    FROM (CARROSSERIE C
    LEFT JOIN alltable T
    ON C.model_marq= T.MARQUE
    AND C.model_name = T.MODELE
    AND C.silhouette = T.CARROS) Left join 
    (select distinct carId, count(carId) 
      from alltable 
      group by carId
      Having count(carId) = 7) as allZones on t.carId = allZones.carId
    GROUP BY model_marq, model_name, silhouette, zone
```

This is the subquery:

```
(select distinct carId, count(carId) 
 from alltable 
 group by carId
 Having count(carId) = 7) as allZones
```

Which you can play with and run separately to evaluate the accuracy of the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I don't have this field (carID) in the table. The primary key is a composite one made of (marq, model, carros) fields. I understand the concept of your query and i'll try to adapt it. I found a solution to my problem that I'll post as an answer but that's a really "complicated" (long) query @TPhe

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SQL on this PC, but you need to use RANK and PARTITION in your first query.  Then you can then manipulate to get your * records.

Example of using RANK/PARTITION:  http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-rank-functions

Answer (score 0):

Remove `zone` from your `group by` and use this expression in the select list:

```
case count(T.ZONE) when 0 then 'ROW' when 1 then min(T.ZONE) when 7 then '*' end
```

If that doesn't work on Access you can translate that to:

```
iif(count(T.ZONE) = 0, 'ROW',
    iif(count(T.ZONE) = 1, min(T.ZONE),
        iif(count(T.ZONE) = 7, '*', '')))
```